# inno setup - custom page with drop-down list and check-box

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to have a custom page That pulls data from an external xml file depending on what is selected in the list changing the check boxes? The list should be built from the xml file. I want to create the list in the first combobox through the existing data in the XML file. Any choice I make in the first combbox will affect the second. Part of the XML: ( i want this list to be my first combobox)

```
<NAMES>
    <name>Simulator-A</name>
    <name>Simulator-B</name>
    <name>Schaarsbergen-IOS-StandAlone</name>
    <name>Simulator-C1-Schaarsbergen</name>
    <name>Simulator-C1-Oirschot</name>
    <name>Simulator-C1-Havelte</name>
    <name>Simulator-C1-Roosendaal</name>
    <name>Simulator-C2</name>
    <name>Simulator-C3</name>
    <name>Simulator-D-Room-171</name>
    <name>Simulator-D-Room-175</name>
    <name>t-Harde-IOS-StandAlone</name>
    <name>t-Harde-AAR-Room</name>
</NAMES>
<Simulator-A>
    <SITENAME>Simulator-A</SITENAME>
    <POSITIONS>
        <NAMES>
            <name>Primary-IOS</name>
            <name>Secondary-IOS</name>
            <name>Trainee1</name>
            <name>Trainee2</name>
            <name>Trainee3</name>
            <name>Trainee4</name>
            <name>Trainee5</name>
            <name>Trainee6</name>
            <name>Trainee7</name>
            <name>Trainee8 </name>
            <name>SimServer</name>
            <name>CGFXBE</name>
        </NAMES>
```

Comment: Why did you delete your original question and posted the same one again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
If you do not want to write page manually use some 3rd party tool for this purpose like **Install Designer** ([website link](http://install-designer.com/)) that generates a lot of code fr you.

Of course you must have an idea how the setup page should behave.

P.S. feel free to ask any questions regarding ID here on SO, I am developer of this tool.